# Hydrogen phase transition

Tags: phase, hydrogen

A sample of hydrogen at a pressure of 7.10×10-2 atm and a temperature of 26.4 K is compressed at constant temperature to a pressure of 18.5

Which of the following are true?
1. One or more phase changes will occur
2. The sample is initially a solid.
3. The liquid initially present will vaporize.
4. The final state of the substance is a liquid

The sample is initially a gas

MY ANSWER: 
I feel that one or more phases will change and that the liquid present will vaporize as it surpasses the supercritical point.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [A sample of hydrogen at a pressure of 7.10×10-2 atm and a temperature of 26.4 K is compressed at constant temperature to a pressure of 18.5 atm](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38014/a-sample-of-hydrogen-at-a-pressure-of-7-10%c3%9710-2-atm-and-a-temperature-of-26-4-k)

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question?

Comment: I accidentally double posted it after putting my answer in the body. Im fixing that now.

Comment: Say, do you think you could screenshot the phase diagram and upload it? It'll make it much easier to see. You can crop out the question since it's already been typed out.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, 1) you already said that the sample is initially a gas - so the "liquid initially present" can't be vapourised if there's no liquid initially present. 2) a note on terminology: the point on the phase diagram is called the *critical point*, and the substance is called a *supercritical fluid*. 3) A supercritical fluid only forms when both $T$ and $p$ exceed that of the critical point. Check the diagram on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)#Liquid-vapor_critical_point